# Multisite converted to Single Site can't add new plugins or new themes

Tags: plugins, multisite, themes

I restored a WordPress site that was previously set up as a multisite to function as a single site. I was only provided with the wp-content folder and the sql dump. I've got the site up and running and can access the admin dashboard. The problem now is I'm unable to add new plugins and themes.

Has anyone encountered this problem before and have any tips on how I can troubleshoot this issue? I'm guessing it may have something to do with permissions. For example, maybe there is a flag in the db that this is a multisite and thus regular admins can't add new plugins. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Check your **wp-config.php** file and remove multisite code.

remove code like

```
define('WP_ALLOW_MULTISITE', true);
```

and

```
define('MULTISITE', true);
define('SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL', false);
define('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'yoursite.com');
define('PATH_CURRENT_SITE', '/');
define('SITE_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
define('BLOG_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
```

Also, check your **.htaccess** file and remove those multisite.